# fastest blit (under winapi)

Tags: winapi, optimization, 2d, blit

I am doing a lot of blitting (write many 2d game prototypes 
in recent months), and I am searching for the fastest blit 
possible Is there maybe anything faster than SetDIBitsToDevice
or StretchDIBits ? Those are about 1-5 ms as far as I remember 
for usual window sizes so they are not terribly fast (hard or 
impossible to write something faster than 200 fps) though 
it is normal, I think, cause RAM itself is not so fast.

Comment: Typically one doesn't worry too much about how long it takes to render a bitmap to the screen, preferring instead to compose things in a back buffer and then blit the entire thing. In any case, your limitation is likely going to be the video hardware rather than the particular function you use to do the blit. You might look into using DirectX, which is likely more highly optimized than the Windows API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

The bottleneck for most machines will be pushing from system memory to graphics memory.

In many cases, there won't be any effective difference between a SetDIBitsToDevice and a BitBlt, but, in some cases, there can be.  If you're running in a low color mode (e.g., 256), then it'll be faster to push 1-byte indexes than 32-bpp pixel data and have it remapped on the card.  (Whether the remapping is handled in the graphics adapter or the system will depend on the driver--I assume.)

I believe the safest thing you can do is BitBlt from a device-dependent (compatible) bitmap.  I don't think this will ever be worse than SetDIBitsToDevice, but it may often be a tie.

I would expect (but haven't tested) that any stretching blit may be slightly more expensive than a straight blit, unless the extra pixels are synthesized on the GPU.

You might consider some of the newer APIs, like Direct2D, which are designed to work closer with the hardware rather than present an idealistic software model.

Whichever solution you choose, I'd be prepared for big performance differences between machines.

Comment: ok, but if one can add something more, I would like to hear it too (I am wery much interested in blitting under winapi)